# Translate inertia tensor & outer product of a vector with itself

Tags: tensor-calculus, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I'm trying to understand a mathematical expression where it's like this:
$$
I' = I+ m \left( d^2  E - \mathbf{d}\otimes\mathbf{d}\right) 
$$
where $I'$ is the new tensor flow, $I$ is the tensor flow, $m$ is mass,  $d$ is the distance from the center of mass to the new origin of the center of mass (as a vector), and $E$ is the identity matrix

What I understand is to translate an inertia tensor, the formula is:
$$
I' = I+ m \left( d^2  E \right)
$$
but then I saw this equation at the beginning which uses outer product of the vector with itself. I'm not able to understand why this outer product is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $E$ is the identity matrix, then you have,
\begin{align}
d^2E-\mathbf{d}\otimes\mathbf{d}&=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}d^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & d^2 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & d^2\end{array}\right)-\left(\begin{array}{ccc}d_x^2 & d_xd_y & d_xd_y \\ d_yd_x & d_y^2 & d_yd_z \\  d_zd_x & d_zd_y & d_z^2\end{array}\right) \\
&= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}d_x^2+d_y^2+d_z^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & d_x^2+d_y^2+d_z^2 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & d_x^2+d_y^2+d_z^2\end{array}\right)-\left(\begin{array}{ccc}d_x^2 & d_xd_y & d_xd_y  \\ d_yd_x & d_y^2 & d_yd_z \\  d_zd_x & d_zd_y & d_z^2\end{array}\right) \\
&=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}d_y^2+d_z^2 & -d_xd_y & -d_xd_y \\ -d_yd_x & d_x^2+d_z^2 & -d_yd_z \\  -d_zd_x & -d_zd_y & d_x^2+d_y^2\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
where we used that $d^2=\mathbf{d}\cdot\mathbf{d}=d_x^2+d_y^2+d_z^2$ in the second step. This final form conforms to the [definition given by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Inertia_tensor).

The moment of inertia is a rank-2 tensor, $I_{ij}$, and represents the moment of inertia (MOI) along the $i$ axis when rotated about the $j$ axis. So the diagonal element $I_{xx}$ is the MOI along the $x$ axis for an object rotated about the $x$ axis. The element $I_{xy}$ is the MOI along the $x$ axis for an object rotating about the $y$ axis. The usage of the outer product simplifies the expression required to write down the MOI tensor.

Answer (score 0):

The first formula you gave is the **parallel axis theorem**, which is the correct way to write down the [inertia tensor under translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem#Tensor_generalization). The inertia tensor $I$ is defined in some body frame, whose origin is some arbitrary point $O$. A procedure to derive this particular inertia tensor is to first consider the inertia tensor $I'$ defined in the body frame with the center of mass $C$ at the origin.

Relative to $C$, the location of $O$ is a vector $\mathbf{d}$. A point in the body located at $\mathbf{r}'$ is thus located at $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}'-\mathbf{d}$ relative to O. So
$$I_{ab}=\sum_{i}m_i[(\mathbf{r}'_i-\mathbf{d})^2\delta_{ab}-(\mathbf{r}'_i-\mathbf{d})_a(\mathbf{r}'_i-\mathbf{d})_b]$$
by definition. Here, $i$ denotes individual particles that make up the rigid body and $a$ and $b$ denote vector components. Expanding it out and using
$$\sum_{i}m_i \mathbf{r}_i'=0$$
in the center of mass frame, the expression becomes:
$$I_{ab} = I'_{ab} + \sum_i m_i(d^2\delta_{ab}-\mathbf{d}_a\mathbf{d}_b) \equiv I'_{ab} + m_{tot}(d^2\delta_{ab}-\mathbf{d}_a\mathbf{d}_b).$$
But $\mathbf{d}_a\mathbf{d}_b = (\mathbf{d} \otimes \mathbf{d})_{ab}$ in index notation. Hopefully this answers your question.